# Rails: I'm having issues with javascript and rails. How do I get typist.js to work?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried get typist.js to work but I'm having a difficult time as it doesn't seem to do anything. Here are the steps I took to get it to work.

https://github.com/positionly/Typist

typist.js in the javascript folder

**application.js**

```
//= require typist
```

**show.html.erb**

```
JavaScript is <strong id="typist-element" data-typist="ugly,not as good an CoffeeScript">great</strong>
```

**applications.css**

```
.selectedText {
  background: #f00;
}
```

but nothing happens, it doesn't do anything. How do I get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the javascript, as it says in the docs. In coffeescript:

`typist = document.querySelector "#typist-element"
 new Typist typist,
   letterInterval: 60
   textInterval:   3000`

Comment: How do I run coffeescript in rails?

Comment: You write a coffee file and you include it into application.js

Comment: the download includes a typist.coffee, do I take that code and just implant that into application.js?